# Watchman crawl failed when run npm start in Mac

Tags: react-native, watchman

I created a project then run `react-native run-ios` and it build successful and it shows No-Bundle URL Present then I run `npm start` Here is error message. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.47.2
watchman -v
4.9.0

[image]

Comment: I guess you upgraded to High Sierra?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `sudo` before the command.
This might not be the right way to deal with this issue but it may get you going.